# Dynamically add arbitrary attributes to a Vue component element?

Tags: vue.js, attributes, vuejs2, components

I want to create a component, that can have arbitrary attributes (data-xxx, for example) THAT THE COMPONENT DOESN'T EXPECT/KNOW ABOUT, from Vue.data at run-time. For example, this doesn't work, but conceptually:

```
Vue.component('text-input',{
  template: `<input type="text" v-model="value" :name="name" {{extra_atts}}>`,
  props:['value','name','extra_atts']
});

.....
//Used elsewhere in Vue app:

<text-input :value="avalue" :name="aname" :extra_atts="dynamic_atts"> </text-input>

const vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    aname: "username",
    avalue: "johnny",
    dynamic_atts: "placeholder='Your name' title='Required' data-extrainfo='arbitrary data'",
  }...
```

so it would be rendered as:

```
<input type='text' value='johnny' name='username' placeholder='Your name' title='Required' data-extrainfo='arbitrary data' />
```

Is there a way to do this in Vue?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Just set the [`inheritAttrs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs) to `false`. Then make use of [`$attrs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs) to bind the attributes on the input element

```
Vue.component('text-input',{
  inheritAttrs: false,
  template: `<input type="text" v-model="value" :name="name" v-bind="$attrs">`,
  props:['value','name']
});
```

Now just add the attributes on the component like you would to a regular input

```
<text-input :value="avalue" :name="aname" placeholder='Your name' title='Required' data-extrainfo='arbitrary data'> </text-input>
```